# Call a method in a WPF app from Flash swf or exe

Tags: wpf, flash, interop

I'm working on a WPF app that needs to host some Flash content.  The plan is create an exe from the Flash content, then invoke the exe from the WPF app (the option of hosting swf content inside a WebBrowser control was discussed but deemed to be too slow for this application).  Is it possible for the Flash application to call a method in the hosting WPF app to provide some feedback?  What IPC methods are available between Flash running as an exe and WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **don't think** this is a good design idea (i've toyed with these ideas before), but here is one lead:

> http://blogs.vbcity.com/drydo/archive/2005/10/18/5586.aspx

Comment: I know it's not good but I'm not the guy making the tech decisions.  Great link.